# Use a rest api PUT method with c# webclient

Tags: c#, http, upload, webclient, put

how can i do a PUT method with a webclient? The web api should upload a CAD-File. With Swagger UI its working properly. Here is the curl from the SwaggerUI:

```
curl -X PUT "https://blablabla/test/api/v1/upload" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization:xxxx" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -d {"file":{},"filename":"jgv","path":"test_1/structure/test_2/test_3","partName":"hello"}
```

And my c# Method:

```
  try
        {
            string fileContent = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }


            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {

                string uri = "https://pdengine-nsu.csi-entw.de/epm_livetest/api/v1/upload";

                wc.Headers["Authorization"] = sessionID;
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "multipart/form-data"; 


                UploadDataModel model = new UploadDataModel
                {
                    file = fileContent,
                    filename = fileName,
                    partName = nameInStructure,
                    path = structurePath
                };

                var modelString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)
                var result = wc.UploadString(uri, "PUT", modelString);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var error = e.Message;

        }
```

I tried already with httpClient, with UploadData,  some variations in my Json.
I always get the Exception: (400) Bad request ....

Thank you for help

Comment: Did you forgot to pass in your DataObject to be serialised into modelString? `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);`

Comment: no i forgot to parse it from my code ;D